# Installing Cargo on Windows with Rust from MSYS2

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, msys2

I've installed Rust on my Windows 7 64-bit system via MSYS2 successfully, but when trying to install Cargo from nightly build, I get the following error from `install.sh`:

```
$ ./install.sh
install: looking for install programs
install:
install: found mkdir
install: found printf
install: found cut
install: found grep
install: found uname
install: found tr
install: found sed
install:
install: processing ./install.sh args
install:
install: CFG_DESTDIR          :=
install: CFG_PREFIX           := /usr/local
install: CFG_LIBDIR           := /usr/local/lib
install: CFG_MANDIR           := /usr/local/share/man
install:
install: validating ./install.sh args
install:
install: verifying platform can run binaries
install: error: can't execute rustc binary on this platform
```

While `rustc` works just fine:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (5ba610265 2014-12-25 18:01:36 +0000)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error message tells it cannot run `rustc`. Can you verify if you can run `rustc --version` in the same console window? Maybe `rustc` was not added to your `PATH`.

Comment: You could try adding `--disable-verify` to your `install.sh` invocation. That skips running the binaries, but might get you in a different problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get `install.sh` to work, but I've had success using the [precompiled binaries available from the Github repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo#installing-cargo-from-nightlies). The README links to 6 precompiled binaries, one each for Windows, OS X, and Linux, for 32 and 64 bit architectures each.

It is a `.tar.gz` file, so you'll need something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unpack it. Once unpacked, you can simply move `cargo.exe` to somewhere that is in your `PATH`.  Since I also install the [Rust nightlies](http://www.rust-lang.org/install.html) to `C:\Rust`, I piggy-back and move `cargo.exe` to `C:\Rust\bin`.

Comment: There is no cargo.exe though in that repository though.

Comment: Right, that's the source code, but the README has links. I'll update my answer to be more clear.